# Blocked port 443 unblocks after "nmap 127.0.0.1"

Tags: linux, networking, port

I meet a very strange behaviour on my CI/CD Linux machine (running 16.04.4 LTS + Gitlab CI in Docker container) and I'm looking for a "path of debug" for the problem.
And the problem is that after every reboot my Gitlab CI's container cannot start, because port 443 (which it's supposed to use). Netstat shows:

```
~$ netstat -ano | grep 443
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

I tried to use `fuser`, `tcpkill` and many more solutions I've found. None of them worked actually. It looks like it is always in use by PID 1.

But then I decided to execute `nmap 127.0.0.1`, which showed me:

```
~$ nmap 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-18 09:31 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00015s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
443/tcp  open  https
5900/tcp open  vnc

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.15 seconds
```

And after that... the port became free - the second execution of this command shows:

```
~$ nmap 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-18 09:31 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00016s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
5900/tcp open  vnc

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds
```

How is this even possible, that `nmap` is able to release a busy port? It works every time.

I'm very curious why this is happening, but I don't know "where" to start my debugging. Or maybe it is a common problem, but I just cannot find any description of that?

Comment: Maybe some application is not properly closing the port when it exits?

Comment: @DanielB but it is happening every time after "fresh" reboot.

Comment: Please try this: When the port is in use unexplainably, just try `echo "blah" > nc 127.0.0.1 443` and see if it comes free. If yes, this points to a not properly closed socket by the upstart process. You could then `grep -r 443 /etc/init` to try and find it.

Comment: @EugenRieck unfortunatelly, it doesn't help.
user@host:~$ netstat -ano | grep 443
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
user@host:~$ echo "blah" > nc 127.0.0.1 443
user@host:~$ netstat -ano | grep 443
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)

EDIT: sorry for the bad formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the system logs on your Ubuntu host? You can use the `journalctl` command for this purpose. One potential reason that I can think of is [socket activation](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html) where systemd (which runs as PID 1) listens on the port and starts a process when something (like nmap) tries to connect to it.

To test this theory, you could for example reboot and run `journalctl -f` to **f**ollow the logs and run nmap again in a different shell.

Apart from checking logs you could also run `systemctl` or `systemctl status` to figure out which services were started or have failed.

Finally it is also entirety possible that a service failed to start earlier in the boot process due to missing dependencies. For example, if your service depends on Docker but does not (implicitly) declare it as such, then the initial attempt to start it at boot could fail whereas a manual start could work by luck since Docker has already been started.

Answer (score 0):

@Lekensteyn, thank you! Your answer led me to the solution.

As it may help some other with similar problem, what I did:

```
~$ systemctl list-units --state=failed
```

This showed, that there are 4 failed services (which are not in use anymore, some legacy solution).

Then, as root:

```
~# systemctl stop <a_failed_service_name> && systemctl disable <a_failed_service_name>
```

executed for every failed unit.

After restart, port 443 is free.